# Determinar el tamaño de una base de datos de Postgresql con c#?

Tags: c#, postgresql

Necesito conocer el tamaño de la Base de datos en C#, normalizar mi programa y así poder realizar los Backup.

se que puedo hacerlo por el pgadmin con

```
select pg_database_size('databaseName');
```

pero quisiera poder hacerlo en C#

Comment: Estas utilizando entity framework o Ado.net? si es Ado utiiza https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0 o este hilo también puede servir https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/b82b918c-7e35-47a5-adf5-e102f60b619f/como-llamar-una-funcion-sql-desde-c?forum=sqlserveres